# SSRS 2012 failed to deploy when having 2 datasets

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to create an automated report in our reporting server. Previously I only have one dataset in my report and all calculation is based on that dataset. I deployed the report to reporting server and everything works fine.

Now I need to further develop the report by adding one other dataset. The data set is created fine by using SQL. Now I have two datasets in my report:

[image]

At this stage, I have done any calculation using DataSet2 but trying to deploy the report to the server. Then I get this error message: **The definition of the report 'xxxx' is invalid**.

I tried to search online but couldn't find the exact case, even though there are some other situations causing this error. So I may need some help here to help me understand what caused this error.

Also once I deleted this DataSet2, report can be deployed successfully.

My current settings in SSRS are:

I have one shared Data Source, these two datasets are both using this common data source. I tried to use two separate data source, it didn't work.

This data source is also deployed in the reporting server.

The two datasets haven't been converted to shared datasets or deployed. Even though I tried to convert and deploy, that didn't make any difference.

The two datasets may have common field names. I also tried to use a totally different set of field names in DataSet2, but still that didn't make any difference.

Not sure if I missed some config settings or what. Appreciated for the help.

Comment: Sounds like you have messed something up in the datasource?  Can you post screenshots of the query and various properties?

Comment: How did you build the report? VS, Report Builder?

Comment: This might provide some help or at least an explanation. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/519e4044-4cff-42dc-9f73-61d3151f755d/error-in-reporting-the-definition-of-the-report-is-invalid-?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: @WEI_DBA . I found the solution and revisit the link you provided. Now I understand. Since I have got 2 datasets now, I need to specify which data set should be used in each table (when there is only one data set, there wasn't such problem). Once I put dataset name in the tables property, the error is gone. Thanks